# Learning Symfony2, having trouble using assets

Tags: symfony, twig, assets, symfony-2.1

I'm  using KnPUniversity's video tutorial on Getting Started with Symfony2, and everthing's been going good except the video is teaching based off of version 2.0.3 and I am using 2.1.x-dev. When I get to a certain point in the video, it directs me to write code block #1 then modify it to more efficiently use code block #2, except code block #2 doesn't work. It doesn't throw any errors, it just fails to actually detect the stylesheets. In the source code of the page, there are zero references to any css style sheets using code block #2. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
{# this causes the page to be styled and works fine #}
{% block stylesheets %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('bundles/event/css/event.css') }}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('bundles/event/css/events.css') }}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('bundles/event/css/main.css') }}">
{% endblock %}
```

.

```
{# this causes the page to be unstyled. Missing stylesheet links in page source #}
{% block stylesheets %}
{% stylesheets
    'bundes/event/css/*'
    filter='cssrewrite'
%}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}">
{% endstylesheets %}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, I had a typo. It's not "bundes" it's "bundles". Problem solved and I'm an idiot.

Answer (score 0):

When you use {{ asset() }} it creates a link to your web (public) directory.

But for the second part Assetic manages the css files - so it looks for the file inside your application and then writes it out into your web directory.

To fix your problem you can change your stylesheets like this:

```
{% stylesheets
    '%kernel.root_dir%/../web/bundes/event/css/*'
    filter='cssrewrite'
%}
```

But I suggest reading more about assetic to understand how you should be managing your css files [Symfony 2 Assetic](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html)

Comment: I think I followed your directions exactly, but I'm still getting the same result. Here is my new code: http://pastebin.com/ff8xHZZ6 I've read the assetic page until I'm blue in the face, but no one seems to have the problem I'm having D:

Comment: Try remove filter and add output='assetic/*.js'   - make sure web/assetic is writable. Finally check your config.yml and check that your bundle is listed in assetic: bundles: [ ]

Comment: edit: also try clearing cache and assetic:dump from the console

Comment: I've tried assetic:dump, app/console cache:clear, assets:install web --symlink. I've got cssrewrite: ~ in config.yml and #bundles [ ] completely commented out, letting assetic work in any bundle. Here is my git repo with all my code: https://bitbucket.org/malon/symblog . I just can't get it to work :(